# Create ContentDocumentLink after insert ContentDocument error

Tags: customsetting, after-trigger, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, collaborationgroup

I have pretty simple requirement but I am facing error and I can't understand what is going wrong.

I need to add **ContentDocumentLink** to add file to **CollaborationGroup** after insert with **C** permission. I am holding CollaborateGroup Id in **SomeCustomSetting__c** to avoid hardcoding Id in TriggerHandlerClass.

This is my Trigger Code:

```
trigger ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument (after insert) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
        ContentDocumentTriggerHandler.afterInsert(Trigger.new);
    } 
}
```

And this is TriggerHandler Code:

```
public with sharing class ContentDocumentTriggerHandler {
    public static void afterInsert(List<ContentDocument> contentDocuments) {
        String collaborationGroupId = String.valueOf(TakedaSettings__c.getInstance().FileGroupId__c);
        List<ContentDocumentLink> newLinks = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();

        for (ContentDocument document : contentDocuments) {
            newLinks.add(new ContentDocumentLink(
                ContentDocumentId = document.Id,
                LinkedEntityId = collaborationGroupId,
                ShareType = 'C',
                Visibility = 'AllUsers'
            ));
        }

        System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(newLinks));

        try {
            insert newLinks;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('$$ Error: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried

```
Id collaborationGroupId = (Id) String.valueOf(SomeCustomSetting__c.getInstance().FileGroupId__c);
```

This is error from logs after inserting some ContentDocument files:

```
DEBUG|$$ Error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
```

Of course in debug with serialized object, all fields are filled correctly.

The weirdest thing is, if I am doing insert from Execute Anonymous in Developer Console, the record is created correctly.
Don't understand what I am doing wrong.
Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: The error may be due to a mismatch between the `ContentDocumentId` and the `LinkedEntityId` in the `ContentDocumentLink` object. You need to make sure that the `ContentDocumentId` refers to a valid file that exists in the org, and that the `LinkedEntityId` refers to a valid collaboration group that you have access to. You can check the IDs of the files and the groups by going to the Files and Groups tabs in Salesforce.

Comment: @TusharJadav all ids are correct. LinkedEntityId is copied from record into custom settings field and content document id is from After insert triggered content document so I am sure that Ids are correct.

Comment: Have you tried using a ContentVersion trigger (checking for VersionNumber=1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the following is: direct retrieval of the `FileGroupId__c` from `SomeCustomSetting__c` as an `Id`, eliminating unnecessary type casting. Also added, null checks are introduced to ensure the `collaborationGroupId` is not null before proceeding with the creation of ContentDocumentLink records. Enhanced error handling is implemented with try-catch blocks for both retrieving the custom setting value and inserting new links. hopefully this helps

Trigger updated

```
trigger ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument (after insert) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
        ContentDocumentTriggerHandler.afterInsert(Trigger.new);
    } 
}
```

Trigger handler updated code

```
public with sharing class ContentDocumentTriggerHandler {
    public static void afterInsert(List<ContentDocument> contentDocuments) {
        Id collaborationGroupId;
        try {
            collaborationGroupId = SomeCustomSetting__c.getInstance().FileGroupId__c;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error retrieving Collaboration Group ID: ' + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        if (collaborationGroupId == null) {
            System.debug('Collaboration Group ID is null');
            return;
        }

        List<ContentDocumentLink> newLinks = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        for (ContentDocument document : contentDocuments) {
            newLinks.add(new ContentDocumentLink(
                ContentDocumentId = document.Id,
                LinkedEntityId = collaborationGroupId,
                ShareType = 'C',
                Visibility = 'AllUsers'
            ));
        }

        try {
            insert newLinks;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error inserting new ContentDocumentLinks: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```